# Installed lxqt on lubuntu 16.04 but can't log into it

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, lubuntu, lxqt

I once installed lubuntu 16.04 to wait for the upcoming 16.10 with lxqt by default prepacked.

Due to lxqt being postponed to the 17.04 release I manually entered
`sudo apt-get install lxqt openbox` in the command line still on 16.04.

After restarting I can't log into lxqt but only into openbox although lxqt was installed with no errors.

Is there a way to add lxqt as a DE to select?

Comment: I suggest you get in touch with _wxl_ or _tsimonq2_. They are Lubuntu team members. See [here](http://lubuntu.me/the-lubuntu-team/) for their contact details.

Comment: Do you have lxqt-session installed? if you do not know can you run apt policy lxqt-session.

Comment: Yes, I do have `~$ apt policy lxqt-session
lxqt-session:
  Installiert:           0.10.0-1ubuntu1
  Installationskandidat: 0.10.0-1ubuntu1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 0.10.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: I emailed them long time ago. The didn't respond